# How to avoid fraction rem value to be less than 1px?

Tags: css, font-size

Let us suppose we have a project where font size is calculated dynamically using `calc` CSS function. Moreover we want to have a border which width is going to be expressed in `rem` (relative to font size).

In some cases pixel size of the border width is less than 1px therefore it's impossible to render.

How to set the border width to be not less than 1px?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, setting a min() isn’t fully supported in most modern browsers, but looking at the CSS 4 spec; there are functions for `max` and `min`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#calc-notation

Example:

```
.type {
  /* Set font-size to 10x 
  the average of vw and vh,
  but don’t let it go below 12px. */

  font-size: max(10 * (1vw + 1vh) / 2, 12px);
}
```

Alternatively you can use a CSS preprocessor or perhaps even a post processor to min the value from the calc;

Comment: Good idea, in the meantime I also had it but somehow max(1px, 2px) becomes... 3 px :D. Anyway I'll figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Did some more digging around, and most browsers don’t support this as of writing this; (it’s still an initial draft)... however safari 11 has support for this (odd but interesting)